# Mview replication

Tags: oracle, replication, oracle-10g

We are setting up a large scale replicated environment and would like to know if there is a way to skip certain dml for eg. deletes during data trasfer with simple mview replication. Also, is it possible to have fast refreshes across databases?

Oracle 10g is the what is used.

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

- large scale replicated environment

Be careful if you have heavy load on your source table. As usual, the behaviour depends on your current environment. In an environment, where we had about 1 million of changes per day, MView refresh wasn't reliable anymore.

- skip certain dml for eg. deletes during data trasfer with simple mview replication

As far as I know, there is no option to skip deletes. If you need more flexibility, then you can try Oracle change data capture.

- Also, is it possible to have fast refreshes across databases?

If you mean different database instances running on different hosts, then the answer is yes.